# Example of WebView tool

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I don't know how to create `WebView` control. I want to display any web page in a `WebView`, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a view based application, in the View, add a UIWebView, and in the .plist add a Application Uses Wi-Fi key, and set it YES. In the ViewController class' .h file make the code look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClassNameHere : UIViewController {

    UIWebView *webView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

In the .m file, add this code:

```
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *webRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:webRequest];
}
```

Finally, in your nib file, connect the webView outlet to the UIWebView. When you compile, it should open Google.